# how to create dynamic class name using dictionary?

Tags: python

Is this possible to create dynamic class name using dictionary in python

```
a={'a':'hai','b','hello'}
```

I expected class name as

```
class hai():
  class content
class hello():
  class content
```

Comment: Why do you even have `a` and `b` as the keys? Also, what does `class content` mean?

Comment: that class name are generated based on key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's not a good idea to create global variables using [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), but here you go using [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and 3 argument version of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

```
>>> a = {'a':'hai','b': 'hello'}
>>> for v in a.values():
    globals()[v] = type(v, (), {})


>>> hai
<class '__main__.hai'>
>>> hello
<class '__main__.hello'>
```